# Curl error when uploading file "failed creating formpost data"

Tags: php, curl

When I trying to upload a file with php and curl, an error occurs "failed creating formpost data". I know that error occur when file path incorrect

```
test.php
...
$postcontent['files'] = '@test.jpg';
...
```

test.php and test.jpg in the same folder. But if I change path to physic path, code run well

```
test.php
...
$postcontent['files'] = '@F:\xampp\htdocs\upload\test.jpg';
...
```

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50060 -
maybe this is why.
I had this problem too and I did the following test. I replaced the '@' with ''
and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to always use an absolute path, like you did in your second example, which works.

Of course, you do not want to hard-code that physical path, so you will want to use either :

- `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the path to the directory that contains the file in which this is written
- Or, with PHP >= 5.3 : `__DIR__` which gives exactly the same path.

So, in your case, you'd probably use something like :

```
$postcontent['files'] = '@' . __DIR__ . '/test.jpg';
```

Or, with PHP < 5.3 :

```
$postcontent['files'] = '@' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.jpg';
```