# PHP Curl: failed creating formpost data

Tags: php, curl

Where ever and on each site I look, they say `wrong file path` cause this error, But I am sure my path is correct and it works last night why not tonight??!!

To prove that the path is correct, `file_exists($path)` return `true`.

I want to send file using Curl and I get `failed creating formpost data`. The path to file which I give to Curl is like below:

```
define('ASSET_PATH', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/asset');

$postfields = array(
    'chat_id'   => $user->user_id,
    'caption'   => $asset->caption,
    'duration'  => $asset->duration,
    'video'     => "@" . ASSET_PATH . "/video/" . $asset->name,
);
```

And when you see the value of `$postfields['video']`, the output is:

```
/home/hosseins/domains/my_domain/public_html/telegram/asset/video/Bottle_Bank.mp4
```

---

**Further Code**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error ( $ch ); //return failed creating formpost data
echo '<br />' . ASSET_PATH . "/video/" . $asset->name; //return named path
curl_close($ch);
```

---

Is there anything wrong with my addressing or problem coming from some where else?
Dudes I'm stuck here, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I am using the sendVideo too, but I have this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961690/trying-to-send-user-video-from-telegram-bot-using-curl did you have any problem like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl treat `@` as path to file, means when you use `@` at first of string, that string considered as file path. So here Curl think my caption is path to file and he can't find that absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not changed the code and stopped working, then it may be the permission of the file that has changed. Make sure the file is with the necessary permissions.

You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805876/curl-error-when-uploading-file-failed-creating-formpost-data).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I check the permission and they're set on `755`, so no problem here, also I checked that link before and according to tha my path is correct as also we see the path in my question.

Comment: Have you tried with other files? Maybe it has something wrong with this file, maybe this file is too big. That's all I can think, I never did upload in that way, I only did file upload writing the multipart/form-data manually.

Comment: Yea I try multiple file but no difference, the point is it ran successfully last night. Codes magic!! Thanks anyway for your time